# how to prove following matrix is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, contest-math

how to prove A is invertible or $\ detA\neq 0$
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac11 & \frac12 & \frac13 & \cdots & \frac1n \\
     \frac12 & \frac13 & \frac14 & \cdots & \frac{1}{n+1} \\
     \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     \frac1n & \frac{1}{n+1} & \frac{1}{n+2} & \cdots & \frac{1}{2n-1}    
     \end{pmatrix}$$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Hilbert matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix), which is a special case of [Cauchy matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix). The determinant is given by
$$\dfrac{\left(\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k!\right)^4}{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{2n-1} k!}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is a positive definite symmetric matrix.

As such it can be diagonalized, and its eigenvalues are all real and positive. So, its diagonalized form is nonsingular, and since it is similar to a nonsingular matrix... it is nonsingular!

Comment: Does this (simply) follow from the calculation of $x^TAx$ or something else?

Comment: @LordSoth Yeah: $xAx^T>0$ for a nonzero eigenvector $x$ implies $x\cdot x\lambda=0$, whence $\lambda\|x\|^2>0$ implies $\lambda>0$.